# Unable to update logged in user's Profile Pic using Swift (Via Sales force iOS SDK)

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios

We are not finding an example to help us create a method to update user profile pic through iOS SDK and have struggled on this feature for the last two days.

1. Is it possible to update logged in user profile image through mobile SDK
2. If Yes how can we do it using swift to achieve this task

Here is our current code:

```
func upload(data:Data, name:String) -> Void {
        restClient.uploadFile(data: data, name: name, description: "", mimeType: "jpeg/png")
            .then { request in
                self.restClient.send(request: request)
            }.done { (response) in
                print(response)
            }.catch { (error) in
                print(error)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to update logged in user profile image through mobile SDK

Yes.

> If Yes how, We are using swift to achieve this task

There's an example of doing this [over on github](https://github.com/wmathurin/MyUserPicReactNative). They do so through the use of the [User Profiles Photo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_user_profiles_photo.htm) resource.

Comment: Not helpful. This repo is not maintained

Comment: @AjaySinghMehra it's still relevant. Did you even try?

Comment: Yes, I tried to setup the thing according to details provided by them, But unable to setup the project on the local system. I also filled an issue on this repo Page, Thanks for Help. Could you help me more on this topic

Comment: @AjaySinghMehra I don't have a Mac to compile or run this code on, unfortunately.